# Laravel 5 - MethodNotAllowedHttpException when validation is false

Tags: php, validation, exception, laravel-5

Always when the validation fails, I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException

routes.php

```
Route::post('download', 'UrlController@download');
Route::post('search', 'UrlController@search');
```

UrlController.php

```
public function download(DownloadRequest $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

DownloadRequest.php

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'format' => 'required|between:1,13'
    ];
}
```

name.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'download']) !!}

{!! Form::select('format', [
    'Please select format',
    'FormatGrp1' => [1 => 'best', 'p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'],
    'FormatGrp2' => [6 => 'p5', 'p6']
]) !!}
```

When "Please select format" is chosen and the form is submitted, I always get this error because "Please select format" has value 0 and i specified values must be between 1 and 13. (Look at DownloadRequest.php)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error didn't come from the validation.

It was because it called the URL to go back and display the errors. And this is the search method.

So cause of the logic in search method the exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this error, in your `if ($validator->fails()) { }` consider that you are going to open the view you are working on for the first time, and add `->withErrors($validator)`

For example:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $exams = Exam::all();
    return view('exams.index', compact("exams"));
}
...

public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'start' => 'required',
            'end' => 'required|after:start'
        ]);

     if ($validator->fails()) 
     {
      $exams = Exam::all();
      return view('exams.index', compact("exams"))->withErrors($validator);
     }

    //Your update code if validator not fails
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't exactly understand what this user was trying to explain as the actual problem or solution - I came across this question as I had the same issue and thought I would describe what I had done in error and how I solved it...

For me, I was building a site where users would submit photos. When the user clicked on the "add photo" it took them to a page where they had to check a box to accept a legal disclaimer. This form with the checkbox was a POST request. After they accepted it they would get re-directed to the photo submission page... WHICH WAS ALSO A FORM WITH A POST REQUEST. This was my issue: back to back POST request pages. If the user entered invalid data on the submission form, or didn't enter data in a field at all Laravel tries to essentially hit the "back button" in your browser and keep the form filled with the data the user did enter. The problem is that the "back" button (or the way the user came to this page) was from a POST request, so it couldn't do it. It gave me the error described above. Once I switched the legal acceptance page to a GET request form and updated the route to match everything started working fine. It was a foolish error on my part, I just hope to mitigate this frustration for others as they are learning to develop in Laravel. Have a great day!